# Зачем нужен prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Зачем существует прототипирование ?
Почему нельзя просто добавлять в объект новые функции `obj.newFunc = function(){}`, а затем использовать их ? Разве это не то же самое что и `obj.prototype.newFunc = function() {}`? Объясните в чём разница и зачем нужен `prototype` ?

Comment: Как правило, свойство prototype используется для предоставления базового набора функциональных возможностей классу объектов. Новые экземпляры объекта "наследуют" поведение прототипа, присвоенного этому объекту. [примеры тут](http://javascript.ru/Object/prototype)

Comment: Всё равно плохо доходит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, что бы понять, зачем нужен `prototype`, надо понять, что такое классы и зачем они нужны:
Пример 'из учебника'

```
function Animal (name) {
    this.name = name
}

var dog = new Animal("Sharky");
```

Что произошло? Мы создали новый объект `dog`, у которого есть свойство `name`, сделали мы это с помощью функции-конструктора `Animal`.
 В данном случае **Animal** - класс, **dog** - экземпляр

Теперь к `prototype`, допустим, мы хотим, что бы у всех экземпляров класс `Animal` был метод `walk()`. Добавлять этот метод к каждому экземпляру после создания, ни какого редактора не хватит, поэтому нам и нужен `prototype`. 
Вкратце - в прототипе ( `prototype` ) содержатся все унаследованные методы/свойства, которое нам выдает класс при создании

```
function Animal (name) {
    this.name = name; // для каждого экземпляра свое имя
}
Animal.prototype.walk = function () { // общая для всех экземпляров
    alert("I can walk");
}

var dog = new Animal("dog");
var cat = new Animal("cat");

alert(dog.name); // dog
alert(cat.name); // cat

// и dog, и cat имеют метод walk
dog.walk(); cat.walk(); // I can walk
```

`Prototype` - это хранилище общих методов и свойств для **всех** экземпляров **одного** класса. Что бы лучше понять, почитай про ООП в js( [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/prototypes) например )

Comment: Скажите а чем тогда отличие, если метод walk засунуть прямо в функцию конструктор

Comment: @ruslik, потому что в самом конструкторе это будет не очень красиво смотреться
`const a = function () {
    a.prototype.m = function() {};
}
const a1 = new a();`

Что не самая приятная запись
А так отличий ни каких нет

Comment: вы о чем, метод засунуть внутрь конструктора

Comment: @ruslik я об этом и написал. По идее разницы ни какой)

Comment: Тогда получается что прототипы не нужны, если можно расширить функцию конструктор внутри самого конструктора. Я думаю истинное предназначение прототипов немного другое

Comment: @ruslik, видимо я не правильно вас понял ,а вы не правильно поняли мой ответ. Посмотрите, как я написал метод внутри конструктора, через прототип. Если вы будите описывать метод через `this` у вас для КАЖДОГО экземпляра будут создаваться методы, что не экономично, как минимум, с точки зрения памяти

Answer (score -1):

Может пример лучше объяснит?

```
var test1 = function() {};
test1.prototype = [1, 2, 3]; // прототипом сейчас является массив
var obj_test1 = new test1();
console.log(obj_test1[2]); // => 3

var test2 = function() {};
test2.prototype = {a: 1};
var obj_test2 = new test2(); // это функция-конструктор
console.log(test2.a); // => "undefined"
console.log(obj_test2.a); // => 1
```

Comment: Ваши примеры не объясняют ничего. Без достаточного количества текста, ваш код - это просто набор не самых популярных(полезных) случаев использования прототипов.

Comment: Ну не знаю, прочитав большое количество литературы, понял после этого примера. А смысла переписывать учебник не вижу.